# Chrome table fluid height needs fix

Tags: google-chrome, html-table

I have a Chrome table problem as I try make fluid height all rows equals height in standard height table, Firefox is working fine!

```
https://jsfiddle.net/vdt745er/
```

```css
table {
 height:300px;
 border:1px solid #000;
 line-height:1;
 border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
table td, table th{
 border:1px solid #000;
 padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0">
  <thead>
   <tr>
      <td colspan="3" scope="col">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <thead>
   <tr>
      <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
      <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
      <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You've hit a bug in chrome. To work around it, remove the `thead` and `tbody` tags.

Edit: chrome bug is https://crbug.com/708345 (cells in thead/tfoot don't receive extra height distribution)